# Using multithreads to calculate data but it does't reduce the time

Tags: c, multithreading

My CPU has four cores,MAC os. I use 4 threads to calculate an array. But the time of calculating does't being reduced. If I don't use multithread, the time  of calculating is about 52 seconds. But even I use 4 multithreads, or 2 threads, the time doesn't change.

(I know why this happen now. The problem is that I use clock() to calculate the time. It is wrong when it is used in multithread program because this function will multiple the real time based on the num of threads. When I use time() to calculate the time, the result is correct.)
The output of using 2 threads:

```
id 1 use time = 43 sec to finish 
id 0 use time = 51 sec to finish 
time for round 1 = 51 sec
id 1 use time = 44 sec to finish 
id 0 use time = 52 sec to finish 
time for round 2 = 52 sec
```

id 1 and id 0 is thread 1 and thread 0. `time for round` is the time of finishing two threads. If I don't use multithread, `time for round` is also about 52 seconds.
This is the part of calling 4 threads:

```
 for(i=1;i<=round;i++)
{
    time_round_start=clock();
    for(j=0;j<THREAD_NUM;j++)
    {
        cal_arg[j].roundth=i;
        pthread_create(&thread_t_id[j], NULL, Multi_Calculate, &cal_arg[j]);
    }
    for(j=0;j<THREAD_NUM;j++)
    {
        pthread_join(thread_t_id[j], NULL);
    }
    time_round_end=clock();
    int round_time=(int)((time_round_end-time_round_start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        printf("time for round %d = %d sec\n",i,round_time);

}
```

This is the code  inside the thread function:

```
void *Multi_Calculate(void *arg)
{
struct multi_cal_data cal=*((struct multi_cal_data *)arg);
int p_id=cal.thread_id;
int i=0;
int root_level=0;
int leaf_addr=0;
int neighbor_root_level=0;
int neighbor_leaf_addr=0;
Neighbor *locate_neighbor=(Neighbor *)malloc(sizeof(Neighbor));

printf("id:%d, start:%d end:%d,round:%d\n",p_id,cal.start_num,cal.end_num,cal.roundth);

for(i=cal.start_num;i<=cal.end_num;i++)
{

    root_level=i/NUM_OF_EACH_LEVEL;
    leaf_addr=i%NUM_OF_EACH_LEVEL;

    if(root_addr[root_level][leaf_addr].node_value!=i)
    {
        //ignore, because this is a gap, no this node
    }
    else
    {
        int k=0;
        locate_neighbor=root_addr[root_level][leaf_addr].head;
        double tmp_credit=0;

        for(k=0;k<root_addr[root_level][leaf_addr].degree;k++)
        {

            neighbor_root_level=locate_neighbor->neighbor_value/NUM_OF_EACH_LEVEL;
            neighbor_leaf_addr=locate_neighbor->neighbor_value%NUM_OF_EACH_LEVEL;


            tmp_credit += root_addr[neighbor_root_level][neighbor_leaf_addr].g_credit[cal.roundth-1]/root_addr[neighbor_root_level][neighbor_leaf_addr].degree;

            locate_neighbor=locate_neighbor->next;

        }
        root_addr[root_level][leaf_addr].g_credit[cal.roundth]=tmp_credit;

    }
}



return 0;
}
```

The array is very large, each thread calculate part of the array.
Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: You only posted the part of the code that calls the thread; you should also post the `Multi_Calculate` method that runs each thread. As far as I can tell, there's nothing in the code you posted that indicates what might be wrong.

Comment: I just updated my code.

Comment: Why do you `malloc()` your `locate_neighbor`, only to assign to it later, leaking the memory?

Comment: I don't free any pointers. Because I worried about freeing pointer at inappropriate  time, so I don't free anything.

Comment: That's inadvisable, and doesn't explain why you even `malloc()` that memory if you never use it. Also, is `root_addr` global? I don't see the definition anywhere in the code you've provided.

Comment: root_addr is global. The original code is very long, I only post key part of it. I use it here: locate_neighbor=root_addr[root_level][leaf_addr].head;

Comment: \*sigh\* that doesn't use the memory allocated by `malloc()`, it just reassigns `locate_neighbor`. If you don't understand that distinction, you're not ready to write multi-threaded code in C.

Comment: Can you give me more details ?

Comment: You need to familiarize yourself with some rather basic concepts regarding pointers and memory management in C. I'm not going to explain this in a comment, and your question is not useful if there are dragons like this lurking in code you haven't posted. Try a tutorial on C pointers and memory management.

Comment: Is this problem resulting that the time is not reduced by multithread ?

Comment: Not likely. While increasing your memory usage *could* slow down your program, this memory is never used and unlikely to impact runtime. Unfortunately, this error is symptomatic of a deep misunderstanding of C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why this happen now. The problem is that I use clock() to calculate the time. It is wrong when it is used in multithread program because this function will multiple the real time based on the num of threads. When I use time() to calculate the time, the result is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug, but if you feel the code is correct, then the overhead of parallelization, mutexes and such, might mean the overall performance (runtime) is the same as for the non-parallelized code, for the size of elements to compute against.

It might be an interesting study, to do looped code, single-threaded, and the threaded code, against very large arrays (100k elements?), and see if the results start to diverge to be faster in the parallel/threaded code?

`Amdahl's law, also known as Amdahl's argument,[1] is used to find the maximum expected improvement to an overall system when only part of the system is improved. It is often used in parallel computing to predict the theoretical maximum speedup using multiple processors.`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law

Answer (score 0):

You don't always gain speed by multi-threading a program. There is a certain amount of overhead that comes with threading. Unless there is enough inefficiencies in the non-threaded code to make up for the overhead, you'll not see an improvement. A lot can be learned about how multi-threading works even if the program you write ends up running slower.